# OpenLayers precache

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using PhoneGap to develop a mobile app in HTML/JS (TypeScript) using OpenLayers and a WMS service. I need to precache certain areas so the app works offline.

I've used the code from CacheWrite and CacheRead controls in OpenLayers to implement my own custom handlers. This allows me to control what storage to use (SQLite instead of localStorage), have a cyclic cache size limit instead of quota-based (keep x last tiles in cache) and to choose "container" for the storage so I can differentiate between "normal cache" and "preloaded cache". The idea is to let users choose areas specific for precaching.

To precache areas I'm attempting to add a WMS layer with "visible:false" to existing map and hook up to "loadend" event for this layer. I have also tried to use "OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed" and set its "preload" property to true.

My problem is that OpenLayers does not download the (invisible) layer. It works fine on the other layers.

I have a "switch map" button in my map (not related to the hidden precache layer), if I use that then "loadend" event is striggered. "Switch map" esentially removes old WMS layer that is displaying map, then adds new one with a new URL (new WMS layer).

How can I preload (precache) maps using OpenLayers?

Comment: It sounds like you are running the layers as baselayers instead of overlays, and in your scenario you may want to run then entire map as overlays http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.allOverlays